# Honda v6 fuel problem?

Tags: honda

My 2000 Honda accord v6 with 250k miles will start and idle fine when cold. When it has sat a while I will drive 50 yards or so and it will stumble and sputter for 3 to 5 seconds and then its fine.

It doesn't feel electrical, more like loss of fuel. There are no signs of fuel leaks where air would get in.

It runs fine after that and usually doesn't return until it sits for an hour or so. Any Ideas??

Comment: Any engine management lights on? Fuel filter checked?